# How to display a block at 100% Vue js scale

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Until I added the JS code, the block was 100% tall, after adding the code, the color is not out of bounds. How do I fix this?https://i.stack.imgur.com/4saaF.png
I tried adding height 100% to all elements. But it doesn't help
Stack won't let me put it out. So I'll just write meaningless text here, sorry

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            
        </div>
        <div id="menuLeft">
             <p 
        v-for="tab in tabs"
        v-bind:key="tab"
        v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
        v-on:click="currentTab = tab">
        {{ tab }}
      </p>


      <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent" class="tab"></component>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(52, 73, 94,1.0);
}

#menuLeft {
    position: relative;
    height: 300%;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: rgba(44, 62, 80,1.0);

}

.tab-button {
    position: relative;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    height: 100%;
}

.tab-button.active {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #34495e;
    height: 100%;
}

.height {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
Vue.component("tab-home", {
        template: "<div>Home component</div>"
      });




      Vue.component("tab-posts", {
        template: "<div>Posts component</div>"
      });
      Vue.component("tab-archive", {
        template: "<div>Archive component</div>"
      });

      new Vue({
        el: "#menuLeft",
        data: {
          currentTab: "Home",
          tabs: ["Home", "Posts", "Archive"]
        },
        computed: {
          currentTabComponent: function() {
            return "tab-" + this.currentTab.toLowerCase();
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve [something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/h5fc934z/)

Comment: How do I create separate content for each tab?

Comment: Do you mean [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/uydcxsL5/)?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62891840/the-vue-cli-code-doesnt-work-the-root-id-contains-an-empty-value